# Authentication failed on Mifare using ACR122S

Tags: nfc

I am very new to NFC devices and hope you can help me up. I tried to Authenticate my Mifare 1k card using ACR122S and it returns error:31. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Log:

Get ATR
< D4 60 01 01 20 23 11 04 10

> D5 61 01 10 09 01 00 04 08 04 C6 F0 FA DC 
>   ATR Value:  D5 61 01 10 09 01 00 04 08 04 C6 F0 FA DC 
>   Card Type: Mifare 1K

Get UID
< D4 4A 01 00 
( X ) Error : 31

Help me? I tried searching for any tutorials or anything regarding this matter. I cant seem to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this from java, check out [NFC Tools for Java](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) and if you're into Android [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) and also [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/).